# Processing places.sqlite file with Linux

Tags: linux, firefox

Firefox stores whole story in that file and what I want to do is to find in it links which contain specific keyword, however what I've tried is not working too precisely and is giving me quite chaotic output: grep --binary-files=text keyword /path/to/places.sqlite. I wonder what would be the best way to process that file and find out all links with keyword using tools on Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You open it with [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Install sqlite with your favorite package manager and run `sqlite3 places.sqlite`. Then you can do SQL queries on the data. Start with `.schema`, then you can do things like `select * from moz_places where url like '%google%';`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wget -cq https://raw2.github.com/websafe/ffbx/master/ffbx.sh \
    && sh ffbx.sh
```

Or just download [ffbx.sh](https://raw2.github.com/websafe/ffbx/master/ffbx.sh) and use it as described in the [README](https://github.com/websafe/ffbx/blob/master/README.md).

Without any params `ffbx` will search all `places.sqlite` files found in ~/.mozilla/firefox subdirectories.

```
ffbx.sh
```

an example result:

```
1391725993809844        ffbx-example    Bookmarks Toolbar       https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/central/  Getting Started
1391725993811277        ffbx-example    Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/help/     Help and Tutorials
1391725993812029        ffbx-example    Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/customize/        Customize Firefox
1391725993812829        ffbx-example    Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/contribute/       Get Involved
1391725993813492        ffbx-example    Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/    About Us
1391725993870487        ffbx-example    Bookmarks Toolbar       place:sort=8&maxResults=10      Most Visited
1391725993870988        ffbx-example    Bookmarks Menu  place:folder=BOOKMARKS_MENU&folder=UNFILED_BOOKMARKS&folder=TOOLBAR&queryType=1&sort=12&maxResults=10&excludeQueries=1  Recently Bookmarked
1391725993871436        ffbx-example    Bookmarks Menu  place:type=6&sort=14&maxResults=10      Recent Tags
1391726063106065        ffbx-example    Unsorted Bookmarks      https://github.com/websafe/ffbx websafe/ffbx · GitHub   Firefox,bookmarks,extract,Bash,script,SQLite
```

The output contains TAB separated columns for each bookmark:

- modification timestamp,
- profile name,
- bookmark folder,
- url,
- title,
- tags.

When used with a parameter:

```
ffbx.sh /path/to/places.sqlite
```

the output is the same, but the `profile name` column is missing:

```
1391725993809844        Bookmarks Toolbar       https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/central/  Getting Started
1391725993811277        Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/help/     Help and Tutorials
1391725993812029        Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/customize/        Customize Firefox
1391725993812829        Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/contribute/       Get Involved
1391725993813492        Mozilla Firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/    About Us
1391725993870487        Bookmarks Toolbar       place:sort=8&maxResults=10      Most Visited
1391725993870988        Bookmarks Menu  place:folder=BOOKMARKS_MENU&folder=UNFILED_BOOKMARKS&folder=TOOLBAR&queryType=1&sort=12&maxResults=10&excludeQueries=1  Recently Bookmarked
1391725993871436        Bookmarks Menu  place:type=6&sort=14&maxResults=10      Recent Tags
1391726063106065        Unsorted Bookmarks      https://github.com/websafe/ffbx websafe/ffbx · GitHub   Firefox,bookmarks,extract,Bash,script,SQLite,
```

[Check the README for more examples.](https://github.com/websafe/ffbx/blob/master/README.md)